# How to Display Flex using inline styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I can't use CSS to style this particular piece. It has something to do with working within the Google Maps Api map. So I have to use inline styling to accomplish the tasks I need. I want to display the image and text side-by-side, however, I cannot successfully implement display flex. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Attempted Inline Styling for Display: Flex**

```
content.push('<div style={{display: flex}}><img id="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + lights + '"><p>Lights in Sky</p></div>');
```

**Code**

```
  var content = [];
  content.push('<h1>Icon Legend</h1>');
  content.push('<img id="legend-icon" widht="25" height="25" src="' + lights + '"><p>Lights in Sky</p>');
  content.push('<img id="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + alien + '"><p>Alien Sighting</p>');
  content.push('<img id="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + ufo + '"><p>Abduction</p>');
  content.push('<img id="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + redBlur + '"><p>Sighting within last week</p>');
  content.push('<img id="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + greenBlur + '"><p>Sighting within last month</p>');
  content.push('<img id="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + blueBlur + '"><p>Sightings over a month</p>');
```

Comment: `style={{ ... }}` is invalid inline styling. the correct way is to use `style=" ... "`. Also ÌD's` have to be unique. You use the same ID multiple times which makes it invalid. YOu have to uses classes in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the regular html syntax:

```
content.push('<div style="display:flex"><img className="legend-icon" width="25" height="25" src="' + lights + '"><p>Lights in Sky</p></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a `<div>` tag (to contain all `<img>` child tags), with attribute `style = "display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;"`

After that, you can put your `content` in.

> You can replace `style = "display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;"` with
> `style = "display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap;"`, if you want the content
> to display on a single line.

For example:

```
<div style = "display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    //push html of content[] here
</div>
```

Finaly, If you have more than one `<img>` tag for content and you want to css for all, you should use `class = "legend-icon"` instead of `id = "legend-icon"`